# Как заменить forEach() на map()?

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста переписать кусочек кода:

```
var markers = [{"lat":18.47960905583197,"lng":149.853515625},{"lat":20.96143961409684,"lng":132.36328125},{"lat":30.600093873550062,"lng":142.294921875}];

var newMarkers = [];

lat_ = 18.47960905583197;
lng_ = 149.853515625;

markers.forEach(function(marker) {
  if(marker.lat != lat_ && marker.lng != lng_) {
    newMarkers.push({
      lat: marker.lat,
      lng: marker.lng
    });
  }
});

console.log(newMarkers);
```

Этот код прогоняет в цикле массив значений и отсеивает одно из них. Я использую forEach(). Но мне хотелось бы вместо forEach() использовать map()

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8nb2cqvj/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сразу на map не выйдет, сначала придётся отфильтровать:

```
newMarkers = markers
  .filter(m => m.lat != lat_ && m.lng != lng_)
  .map(m => ({lat: m.lat, lng: m.lng}));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но тогда получается, что map() не нужен? Это ещё лучше

Comment: Ага, если других свойств нет, то не нужен)